# How to achieve this menu?

Tags: javascript, menu

Are there any tutorials (some JavaScript framework perhaps?) that will explain how to produce a top-level menu like the following?

http://www.clinique.co.uk

Where the drop down part can be any width and can contain images/links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jQuery](http://jquery.com). It makes creating JavaScript UIs much easier. There are also a large number of plugins for it.

And even if you can't find a tutorial to make a menu specifically like the one on that site, it should be simple to adapt a regular dropdown menu—granted that you know JavaScript and CSS.

E.g. most dropdown menus use nested `UL` elements to create a hierarchical menu/list. The `LI` elements represent each menu item, which can contain anything from a text label to a submenu. A basic nav bar with dropdown menus might look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">menu 1</a>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>foo</li>
                <li>bar</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">menu 2</a>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>foo2</li>
                <li>bar2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">menu 3</a>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>foo3</li>
                <li>bar3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To create the look you want, you'd just add images to your `menu` divs and apply the appropriate CSS:

```
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>foo</li>
                <li>bar</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="your-image" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest learning some [jQuery](http://jquery.com) first. It's very easy to learn, and there's a ton of great plug-ins!

For example: [Menu Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/44).

If you're using ASP.NET, then Rick Strahl (aside from the official jQuery site) has a great blogpost about it: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/459197.aspx.